# n-th power of uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm not sure wether the following is true:

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous funtion over the reals with f(0) = 1 and let $t\in \mathbb{R}$ does it hold that $lim_{n\to\infty}\ f(\frac{t}{n})^n = 1 \forall\ t\in\mathbb{R}$?

This occured in a (maybe fruitless) try to solve a problem on my probability theory problem sheet dealing with characteristic functions of random variables.

Thanks for any hints or comments!

Comment: *Uniformly* continuous will certainly not play a role. As the limit depends only on points near $0$, "uniformly continuous" cannot give any better results than "continuous at $0$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=1+x$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\tfrac tn)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac tn\right)^n=e^t $$

---

And with $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1+x\cos\frac1{x}& 0<|x|<\frac2\pi\\1&x=0\\1&|x|\ge1\end{cases}$$
and $t=\frac 1\pi$ we even have $f(\frac tn)^n=\left(1\pm\frac tn\right)^n$, i.e., no convergence at all (the odd and even subsequence converge to $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$, respectively).

Comment: yeah thanks, I tried to construct something like this, but I couldn't see it!